# Django 1.6 messages not showing up

Tags: django, django-messages

I followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages) to import necessary stuff into my settings, views and template. However, no messaging is showing up.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
```

Example view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, "News was added") 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = NewsForm()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        return render_to_response('news/add_news.html', args)
```

In base.html I have:

```
  {% block messages %}
            {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">   
            {% for message in messages %}
               <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
             {% endfor %}
             </ul>
        {% endif %}
  {% endblock messages %}
```

How should I debug this?

Comment: How are you displaying the message in the template?

Comment: Also, you may run into problems with that layout of POST/GET blocks; if a user submits a form but it doesn't validate there will be an error as no response is returned

Comment: Well I added the messages block. The news items are created with no issues so I assume forms are validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) makes use of a [context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to deliver the messages to the template. To make sure the variables from your context_processors are actually added to the context you render your template with, you have to use a `RequestContext` in your view.

> If you’re using the context processor, your template should be rendered with a RequestContext. Otherwise, ensure messages is available to the template context.

You are using the [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) method which doesn't do this by default. You either need to specify the use of a `RequestContext` or use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function instead which does this by default

```
return render_to_response('news/add_news.html',
                      args,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Adding 'context_instance=RequestContext(request)' solved the problem.  Actually return render(request, 'news/add_news.html', args) looks much clear so it'd be good to add it to the answer too. Many thanks Timmy.